# Schwartz lemma problem $f: \mathbb{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}-(-\infty,0]$ and $f(0)=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f(0)=1$, and for $f(z)$ defined and holomorphic on the unit circle. Also suppose that the image of $f(z)$ doesn't include $(-\infty,0]$. Then show there exists a $C$ such that for all such functions $f(z)$, we have $|f(z)|\leq C$ for $|z|\leq 0.5$

My thoughts.
In general I think we want to use Cauchy's formula, either to gain a bound on the derivative or on $f(z)$ directly. Cauchy's theorem can also give rise to constants independent of the function used. Also I think we need to apply either a $\log$ or square root function to use the condition on the range of $f(z)$ (without which the theorem doesn't hold).

I tried several things. The first was to note that a square root exists. Let $g(z)$ be the square root with the principal branch, and then we get $\frac{-\pi}{2}<Arg(g(z))<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Hence the real part of $g(z)$ is greater than zero.

Let $h(z) = \exp(-g(z))$. Then the modulus of $h(z)$ is less than 1. In particular we get using cauchy's theorem that
$-g'(z)\exp(-g(z))=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{D(z,\frac{1}{4})}{\frac{h(w)}{(w-z)^2}dw}$. Taking moduli we can get an elementary inequality of the form $|h'(z)|\leq C$, so $|h(z)-h(1)|\leq C|z|$, but it was unclear to me how to proceed further. Without some upper bound on the real part of $g(z)$ it seems hard to convert these inequalities into one which can give an upper bound on $|g'(z)|$ and hence allow us to solve the problem.

Attempt 2.
I also tried variation of things like looking at $h(z)=\log(f(z))$. This function has $h(0)=0$. Suppose there were a finite supremum for $f(z)$ on the domain, then one could try things like $\frac{\log(f(z))}{\log(M)}$. Applying the schwartz lemma then yields that $|\log(f(z))| \leq |z \log(M)|$, and we get $|f(z)|\leq M^{|z|}$

Comment: Consider $g$ the unique Riemann map from the disc to the cut plane with $g(0)=1, g'(0)>0$ (it is $4k+1$ where $k(z)=z/(1-z)^2$ is the famous Koebe function); applying Schwarz lemma to $g^{-1}\circ f$ one gets that $f(z)=g(u(z))$ for some self map of the disc with $|u(z)| \le |z|$ and the result follows with $C$ the maximum of $|g|$ on the circle of radius $.5$

Comment: (1) The title says $f(0)=1$ but the first sentence of the question says $f(1)=1$; you might mean both, but I doubt it. (2) After noting that $g(z)$ maps the disc onto the right half-plane, did you consider composing it with a Möbius transformation to map the half-plane back to the disk (and map $1$ to $0$)? Schwartz's Lemma should tell you something about the composite map, but I on't guarantee how useful it will be.

Comment: sorry it should be $f(0)$=1, i was quite tired when i wrote this

Comment: @Conrad do you mind explaining this a little further? for context, this is a past exam question and we would have c. 30mins to answer the question, and haven't covered Koebe functions in the course.

Comment: @Conrad ok i think i've worked out how to prove the koebe function does that (via mobius maps to a half plane, and then squaring and rotating appropriately. The rest of the proof makes sense. are there other approaches also?

Comment: You do not need the koebe function unless you need explicit $C$; Riemann mapping theorem and Schwarz lemma are enough since there is always a (unique up to a inner scaling - $g'(0)>0$ fixed that) $g$ and then the image of $f$ on any disc centered at the origin is included in the image of $g$ so is uniformly bounded for all such $f$; this is part of subordination theory which is the sort of analogue of inequalities between functions in the complex case where the notion of order doesn't apply, but image inclusion substitutes for that to some extent